# "The updated schedule will be informed soon" Can this sentence be converted to active voice?

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice, active-vs-passive

> The updated schedule will be informed soon

I can't figure out the subject, verb & object from this sentence. So I can't convert this to active voice.

Does this sentence have any mistakes at all?

Answer (score 2):

It does contain an error. The word "informed" is used incorrectly. A schedule can't be informed. The public can be informed of the schedule, that is, information about the schedule can be given to the public.

In your sentence, the word "published" could be used:

> The updated schedule will be *published* soon.

An active voice version might be

> They will publish the updated schedule soon.

Comment: In several Latin-based European languages, the verb **to inform** is wrongly translated intransitively. Popular translations into English commonly begin: **We inform that....**. Your question probably relates to this error. This may well change in time. The verb ** to warn** was once in a similar position. These days it's quite acceptable to say: **They warned that......** without saying who was warned.

Answer (score 0):

The following is very bad English:

> The updated schedule will be **informed** soon

Only people can be **informed**.

A schedule is not a person.

> - "I **informed** my cousin about my father's death."
> - "I was **informed** about Janet's promotion at work from her mother."

You cannot **inform** a schedule.

The following two sentences have almost the same meaning.
All of the sentences in the block below are wrong.
Each sentence assumes that the schedule is a person.

> The updated schedule will be **informed** soon
> Soon, we will **inform** the updated schedule.
> Soon, we will **tell** the updated schedule about our news.
> We will **talk** to the schedule soon.
> Soon, we will **call** the schedule on the phone.

The sentences above were bad. However, the sentences below are good:

> I will send you the updated schedule soon.
> I will inform you of the updated schedule soon.
> I will let you know what the schedule is soon, but I do not have it right now.
> I will give you the updated schedule soon, but I do not have it right now.
> I will inform you about the schedule changes tomorrow.

Comment: "Only people can be informed." An organization can be informed (admittedly that is something of a quibble). And the adjectival form can be variously used: informed consent, informed opinion, informed judgement, etc.